# Why is this statement about generators of groups true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, modules

Let $G$ be free abelian of rank $n$ and $H \subseteq G$ a subgroup also of rank $n$. It is known that $G/H$ is finite, in fact a direct sum of at most $n$ cyclic groups. Thus we can write $$G/H = \langle x_1,\ldots,x_n | d_1x_1 = \cdots =d_nx_n = 0\rangle,$$ where the $d_i$'s are the orders of those cyclic groups. From here why does it follow that there is a basis $\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n$ of $G$ such that $d_1\beta_1,\ldots ,d_n\beta_n$ is a basis for $H$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $G/H\simeq \mathbb Z_{d_1}\oplus\cdots\oplus\mathbb Z_{d_n}$. (Note that some of $d_i$'s can be equal to $1$.)

Set $D=\operatorname{diag}(d_1,\dots,d_n)$. This matrix is equivalent to a matrix $C=\operatorname{diag}(c_1,\dots,c_n)$ (called the [*Smith Normal Form*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) of $D$) with $c_1\mid\cdots\mid c_n$, that is, there are $U,V\in\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb Z)$ such that $UDV=C$. One knows that there exists a basis $g_1,\dots,g_n$ in $G$ such that $c_1g_1,\dots,c_ng_n$ is a basis of $H$. Note that $(c_1g_1,\dots,c_ng_n)^T=C(g_1,\dots,g_n)^T$. Since $C=UDV$ we get that $UDV(g_1,\dots,g_n)^T$ is a basis of $H$. But $U$ is invertible, so $DV(g_1,\dots,g_n)^T$ is also a basis of $H$. On the other side, since $V$ is invertible it follows that $(x_1,\dots,x_n)^T:=V(g_1,\dots,g_n)^T$ is a basis of $G$. Finally we get that $D(x_1,\dots,x_n)^T$ is a basis of $H$, i.e. $d_1x_1,\dots,d_nx_n$ is a basis of $H$.

Comment: By the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups, *a priori* don't we have $d_1|d_2|\ldots | d_n$?

Comment: @BenjaLim The fundamental theorem is one thing, and an *arbitrary* decomposition as a direct sum of cyclic groups is other thing.

Comment: when you say "One knows that there exists a basis $g_1,\ldots$ ... is a basis for $H$", that is basically following the argument in my comment to rschwieb's answer below yes?

Comment: Of course it is! This argument is the key for proving the fundamental theorem and can be found in many textbooks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since $H$ and $G$ are free $\Bbb Z$ modules of the same rank, there is an isomorphism between them which you can express in whatever basis you like. The statement you have supplied "there exists a basis... such that..." amounts to changing bases so that the transformation matrix becomes diagonal.

With your knowledge of how the invariant numbers work, I think this is what you need for your question.

Comment: Suppose that $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ is a basis for $G$ and $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ is a basis for $H$. Then we can say that $y_i = \sum a_{ij} x_j$. Now let $A = (a_{ij})$. Then the Smith Normal Form shows that there are invertible matrices $B,C$ so that $BAC = D$ where $D$ is diagonal. Now let $y = (y_1,\ldots,y_n)^T$, $x = (x_1,\ldots,x_n)^T$. Then we have 
$$\begin{eqnarray*} BAx &=& DC^{-1}x \\
&=& By.  \end{eqnarray*}$$

Now because $B$ is invertible, $By$ will also be a basis for $H$. $C^{-1}x$ is also a basis for $G$ and hence the problem is proven. However, how do we know that the elements on

Comment: the diagonal of $D$ are precisely $d_1,\ldots,d_n$?

Comment: @BenjaLim My memory was telling me this was incorporated in the proof about SNF, and that the connection to the invariants (which I'm assuming is what the $d_i$ stand for) was laid out there.

Comment: The $d_i$ in the OP's question above are the orders of those cyclic groups.

Comment: @BenjaLim I think the issue here is that the OP was not specific enough about how the $d_i$ were chosen and what constraints are on them. *It seems* that the invariant factors were intended. By quoting the OP at me again, for some reason, it seems you might find this unreasonable? Without those constraints, I definitely agree that the problem is not clear.

Comment: Looking at the post of the OP he does say that $d_i$ are such that $G/H \cong \Bbb{Z}/d_1 \oplus \ldots \oplus \Bbb{Z}/d_n$. Those $d_i's$ are thus the orders of those cyclic groups.