# Problem from Marcus' Number Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I have been stuck on the 27th problem of the 2nd chapter from Marcus' Number Fields. In it we're given $G$, a free abelian group of rank $n$ and its subgroup $H$, which is again of rank $n$. Now, consider the quotient group $G/H$. It is easy to see that this is a finite group. Next, we are asked to show that it is a direct product of at most $n$ cyclic groups and use it to show that we'll be able to find a set of generators $\beta_1, \beta_2, . . . ,\beta_n$ for $G$ such that $k_1\beta_1, k_2\beta_2, . . ., k_n\beta_n$ are generators for $H$ for suitably chosen integers $k_i$.

I was able to prove the part about the direct products, but couldn't use it to get the generators part of the problem.

Comment: Is there any basic algebra textbook which doesn't prove this?

Comment: @user26857 I had a look at Dummit-Foote, but I couldn't find anything useful. Can you recommend a source?

Comment: What about the Theorem 4 on page 460 (from the book you mentioned)?

Comment: @user26857 That seems fair. But, the way the problem has been posed in Marcus, the result should follow from the direct product property. That's what I am looking for currently

Comment: Same question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269731/why-is-this-statement-about-generators-of-groups-true